# Word Count returns an array (of arrays of the form [word, count]) representing the frequency of each word

Tags: ruby

```
str = 'put returns between paragraph put returns between paragraph put returns between paragraph'

def word_count(string)
  resut= []
  return result = string.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
end

def parse_word(word)
  word.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/, " ")
  word.downcase!
  @yoo=    word
end

result =word_count(str)
print result, "\n\n"
res2 = result.select { |pair| pair[1] > 1 }  `#Error coming`
```

I am getting OutPut
**

- OutPut

**

```
{"put"=>3, "returns"=>3, "between"=>3, "paragraph"=>3}
```

I need  OutPut Like this 
**

- OutPut

**

```
{"put"=>3, "returns"=>3, "between"=>3, "paragraph"=>3}
```

and

```
put: 3
returns: 3
between: 3
```

but the main problem is that he gave us the code to do that but i cant able to understand it

I am not getting this what this code will do can anyone help me ...And modify it so it can work

The following processes the first paragraph of put returns ... Note that ss is an array of those words that occur at least twice in this paragraph.

```
nect = ss.select { |p| p[1] > 1 }
nect .sort.each do |key, count|
 puts "#{key}: #{count}"
end
```

Comment: Not sure I totally understand the question, but maybe change `ss.select { |p| p[1] > 1 }` to `ss.select { |_, v| v > 1 }`?

Comment: The following processes the first paragraph of put returns ... Note that ss is an array of 
those words that occur at least twice in this paragraph.

Comment: This is a pure Ruby question, so I suggest you remove the Rails tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

module WordCount
    def self.word_count(s)
        count_frequency(words_from_string(s))
    end

```
def self.word_count_from_file(filename)
    s = File.open(filename) { |file| file.read }
    word_count(s)
end

def self.words_from_string(s)
    s.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
end

def self.count_frequency(words)
    counts = Hash.new(0)
    for word in words
        counts[word] += 1
    end
    # counts.to_a.sort {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
    # sort by decreasing count, then lexicographically
    counts.to_a.sort do |a,b|
        [b[1],a[0]] <=> [a[1],b[0]]
    end
end
```

end

def word_count(s)
    WordCount.word_count(s)
end